# How to use GDAL Correlator?

Tags: gdal, imagery, coregistration

I need to align several images using FOSS. There is [Correlator tool](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/Correlator) in GDAL ([source](https://github.com/migal-drew/GDAL-correlator)) that seems to be suitable for the job. But I was unable to find documentation for it or a tutorial. Can someone explain what does it actually do and how to use this tool? The only help I could find is in [this document](http://www.gdal.org/gdalmatching_8cpp.html#details)

Comment: Also couldn't find much but there is some kind of documentation within the source files (in the form of comments), particularly [GDALCorrelator.h](https://github.com/migal-drew/GDAL-correlator/blob/master/src/headers/GDALCorrelator.h) which might provide some insight.

Comment: Seems that everything that there is just [this document](http://www.gdal.org/gdalmatching_8cpp.html#details)